# No webpage was found for the web address: https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/ when publishing on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

So, I'm publishing an app on Azure and I'm getting this error message:

> This mywebsite.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found
> No webpage was found for the web address: https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/
> HTTP ERROR 404

Locally the app is working normally, including already connected with the remote DB (on azure and with all permissions granted), but when I try to publish the app, it publishes but as a 404 error page from the browser.

Any thoughts about how to fix that?

That's the config that allow me to deploy on azure

[image]

To complement, I have the swagger on my app, even when I type `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/swagger` or `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html` I have the same 404 error.

Comment: The first link is working for me. Perhaps this is a problem with your local network or proxy server?

Comment: Yes, first link is working for me too! https://i.imgur.com/krPBa3y.png

Answer (score 0):

There could be various root causes for 404 error messages for users who are experiencing the same problem. Sub-status codes will aid in your understanding of the problem.

You can use the [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream) to see if the site files have been distributed correctly. Also, if you haven't done so already, [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) for web apps in Azure App Service to verify the whole problem details and underlying cause.

Comment: I did it, I've checked the same answer in a couple of posts related, and I already have diagnostics logging enabled and I'm checking the logs by kudu and Log Streaming on azure app service panel, but I just get 404 in the logs. This is an example of response I'm getting by log: `2022-05-19 14:23:49 MYAPP GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=f29696cf-7b07-4b69-b9ca-36758793dcbf 443 - <MY IP> Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/101.0.4951.67+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=<A HASH HERE>;+ARRAffinitySameSite=<A HASH HERE> - myapp.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 353 1646 0`